# PHP laravel. link to dynamic page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a categories table in my DB.

There are 3 root categories and subcategories within them which contain products. 
User can navigate through them in `products` section.

The question is: how can I add a link on the homepage to one of these root categories?

Clarification: I can not simply fetch all root categories and display them on the page. I need only 2 of them.

I have 2 icons on the home page that should take the user to these 2 categories. I can not hard-code the `href` attribute of the link because user can change the categories in admin section however he wants.

So basically my understanding is that I should fetch somehow the category from the DB and then generate a link but in the other hand, I have no clue which category I should fetch.

I can not fetch by name, I can not fetch by Id or by slug. I can not fetch all root categories. how should I go around it?

Comment: Add a column 'order' and fetch them by order. Let the users order their categories as well, in the admin section. I suggest you download magento and get inspiration from their e-commerce platform.

Comment: @Mysteryos thanks for the hint. Magento - no thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are the only two root categories you have. 
I'm assuming that you have an hierarchy where the root categories have a "parent_id" field with a null value.

You only need to Fetch all categories where parent_id is null.

If that is nos that issue, if you have multiple root categories but you only need two, you can add a flag field like "Home" as a boolean and set True to those you want on the main page. The problem here is that you will have two true categories and all others fields will be false, with no use ever.

A third option, you can create a new HomeCategories entity, and relate to the categories you want on the home.

Comment: thank you, I went with your third approach, makes sense for me!